# Moving in even though my town is full?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I really want this villager to leave because he is pretty mean. I've been doing the usual, like hitting her with a shovel/net and even using pitfalls. It took days to get her to leave. A villager I wanted came back. She's been asking to play games but no sign of charades or any other game. Can she still move in?

Answer (score 2):

Has the villager left? If she has, then the other villager can move in, if she hasn't, then sorry, they can't :(